# Values extracted from NetCDF not matching original raw data

Tags: python, netcdf

I am working with monthly rainfall data from University of Delaware which is available as a NetCDF from [NOAA](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.UDel_AirT_Precip.html) and raw text from UDel's [homepage](http://climate.geog.udel.edu/~climate/html_pages/Global2014/precip_2014.tar.gz). I would prefer to use the NetCDF format but when I extract values, these don't match what the ones in the raw data files.

Can you suggest why the comparison might not be working?

```
# Extract data
from netCDF4 import Dataset
ncfile =  "C:/precip.mon.total.v401.nc"
fnc = Dataset(ncfile, 'r')
print fnc.variables
lat = fnc.variables['lat']
lon = fnc.variables['lon']
monthyear = fnc.variables['time']
rain = fnc.variables['precip']
# Manually check values / example one
print lat[37] # 71.250 
print lon[0]-180 # -179.750 (need to subtract 180 because the lon values in the nc file range from 0 to 360)
print rain[0:12, 37, 0]*10
# Wrong output: [-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --]
# Another example
print lat[46] # 66.750 
print lon[54]-180 # -152.750 (need to subtract 180 because the lon values in the nc file range from 0 to 360)
print rain[0:12, 46, 54]*10
# Wrong output: [26.6   30.5   23.6   27.1   29.7   26.1   101.9   44.4   31.   79.8   49.9   29.7]
```

Acc to the raw data the values corresponding to lon -179.750 and lat 71.250 are:

```
0.0     5.4     0.0     4.0     7.3     3.9    33.5    63.2     9.4     4.0     8.0    23.6
```

In case of lon -152.75 and lat 66.75, the extracted data should have been:

```
11.6    11.4    26.4    28.5    14.3    31.7    30.5    67.0    59.6    22.9     9.1    33.3
```

(The netCDF may be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zi0imr5i1qlqgs/precip.mon.total.v401.nc?dl=0 and the raw data file is available here https://www.dropbox.com/s/6klwmj37kvwj46w/precip.1900?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AndreJ's hint was key in solving the issue. If one plots the data, one realizes that the map is centered at the pacific and not at (0, 0)

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
imgplot = plt.imshow(rain[1, :, :])
imgplot.set_cmap('RdYlGn')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show
```

Applying the correct transformation i.e. `(lon + 180)*2 + 360` for all east longitudes and `(lon)*2` for all west longitudes solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you subtracting 180 from the lon values, e.g., "print lon[0]-180"? As I understand the NC file, the left edge of the data grid is 0.25, not -179.75. Which suggests you are extracting values 180 degrees away from where you think you are.

Comment: You are right that the left edge is 0.25. But since lon values in the nc file range from 0 to 360, I was merely pointing out that lon[0] corresponds to -179.750 (in the raw data the lon values range from -180 to +180).

Comment: No, you are wrong in that. Take a look at the pictures at the university site: They start at Greenwich meridian, not the pacific. So half of the world has the right longitude, and the other half needs 360 to be subtracted.

Comment: Look at a CDL representation of the NC file metadata; it says "lon:actual_range = 0.25f, 359.75f ;" and if you do an ncdump on the file, you will see that lon = 0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25, 2.75, 3.25, etc.